why some users are getting error facebook login unavailable while there aren't any required actions?
some of the users are getting the error Facebook Login is currently unavailable for this app, since we are updating additional details for this app but there aren't any issues or required actions on the developer account Error
Some users try to use facebook login through my app but they get the exception that the feature is unavailable
